# How to display next schedule time for a TSM node?

Tags: backup, scheduling

```
0:root@SERVER:/SERVER/fs_111 # dsmc q schedule
IBM Tivoli Storage Manager
Command Line Backup-Archive Client Interface
  Client Version 6, Release 4, Level 0.1  
  Client date/time: 03/09/2014 15:08:27
(c) Copyright by IBM Corporation and other(s) 1990, 2012. All Rights Reserved.

Node Name: SERVER_111
Session established with server TSM03: AIX-RS/6000
  Server Version 5, Release 5, Level 5.2
  Server date/time: 03/09/2014 15:08:27  Last access: 03/09/2014 15:02:58

    Schedule Name: foo
      Description: 
   Schedule Style: Classic
       Action: Incremental
      Options:  
      Objects:  
     Priority: 4
   Next Execution: 2 Hours and 7 Minutes
     Duration: 2 Hour 
       Period: 2 Day  
      Day of Week: Any
        Month: 
     Day of Month: 
    Week of Month: 
       Expire: Never

0:root@SERVER:/SERVER/fs_111 #
```

From the output of the "dsmc q schedule" I can see that the next backup for this nodeid will be in "2 Hours and 7 Minutes". I can also see the "Server date/time".

**My question**: How can I get the next schedule time? It would be the server time plus next execution time. So in this example: "03/09/2014 17:15:27"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a rough way to do what you want. It makes a few assumptions about the nature of the output but should provide you with a template for how you can expand a more exact solution to your problem.

#### Example

For this demo I'm taking the output you provided and putting it into a text file so I can "simulate" the TSM command running. That file I'm calling `tsm_output.txt`.

The following code will parse out the next execution time:

```
$ cat tsm_output.txt  | grep 'Next Exec' | awk '{print $3, $6}'
2 7
```

The first assumption my solution makes is that the nature of this output will be such that it's always Hours & Minutes. Building off of this we can then expand the hours & minutes so that they're seconds.

```
$ cat tsm_output.txt | grep 'Next Exec' | awk '{print $3"*60*60+"$6"*60"}' 
2*60*60+7*60
```

We can then pipe that output to a command line calculator tool called `bc`:

```
$ cat tsm_output.txt | grep 'Next Exec' | awk '{print $3"*60*60+"$6"*60"}' | bc
7620
```

So with the number of seconds, we can enlist the help of the `date` command to calculate the time from NOW + those seconds:

```
$ date -d "$(cat tsm_output.txt | grep 'Next Exec' | \
    awk '{print $3"*60*60+"$6"*60"}' | bc) seconds"
Wed Mar 12 06:22:42 EDT 2014
```

This tells date to display the time + the seconds of offset. This is of the form `date -d "X seconds"`.